# How can I show this homotopy is continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis

this is the homotopy that transforms the unit circle into the unit square in $\mathbb{C}$.  The function is defined by $h(t,s) = (1-s)e^{2\pi it} + s$*$\{$... a piece-wise function consisting of linear functions of t for different intervals of t.

Answer (score 0):

$h$ is a composition of products and sum of continuous functions, so it is continuous.

Comment: Okay, it's the fact that its piecewise that threw me off.

Comment: Yeah piecewise is a problem for differentiability but not for continuity if the different parts are linked like in this case.